# AngularJS UI Router Children

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

fairly new to angular so excuse me if I'm making an obvious mistake here.

I'm building a form application, the forms have shared sections so imagine an application layout like below...

- forms

  - form1
  - form2
- formSections

  - section1
  - section2

I'm using ui-router and each section has it's own pages and so it's own children.

```
$stateProvider.state('section1', {
  url: '/section1',
  templateUrl: 'section1.html'
})

.state('section1.page1', {
  url: '/page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})

.state('section1.page2', {
  url: '/page2',
  templateUrl: 'page2.html'
});
```

My form has a similar setup, but with no children as I'm trying to include those dynamically...

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('form1', {
    url: '/form1',
    templateUrl:  'form1.html'
  });

  // In an ideal world...
  var sections = ['section1', 'section2'];

  // Now run some sort of function that includes section1 & section2
  // That then allows me to navigate to /form1/section1 etc.

}]);
```

What I'm trying to do is configure each 'form' with the appropriate child views. So that form1 has section1, section2 and their respective children views which will allow the following navigation...

- /form1
- /form1/section1
- /form1/section1/page1

and so on...

Thanks in advanced for any advice / help you can offer!

**edit**

I did manage to get this sort of 'working' how I wanted by defining a parent of 'form1' on the sections but obviously that prevents any hope of getting it then working for form2 :)

Comment: So you want `section1` and `page1` to be shared under both `form1` and `form2`? Have you looked at named ui-views? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views

Comment: So section1 manages it's own views of page1, page2 etc and that's all working wonderfully. However, right now to get to section1 you end up navigating to /section1 where as I'd like to nest it underneath the respective form so /form1/section1/page1.

Comment: I've managed to do that by setting a parent on section1 of 'form1' but that means the section cant be nested by form2 (I think anyway). My ideal solution would be adding some sort of config into form1 `var sections = ['section1, 'section2'']` and to create some sort of function that would then nest those sections underneath dynamically.

Comment: Where are your `form1` and `form2` states at? Show more of the code. But, yes, you need `form1` to be a parent to `section1`. Is `section1` supposed to "be under" both `form1` and `form2`?

Comment: I've included some extra code that shows the form1 state and my desired intention. I'm trying to avoid the need to have to re-define the views over and over but it looks like I might have to (similar to this https://github.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can dynamically build the state hierarchy. `stateProvider.state()` can take an object, so start with arrays of objects for each of your areas and build up a single array of your states:

```
var states = [];
var forms = [
    {
        name: 'form1',
        url: '/form1',
        templateUrl: 'form1.html'
    },
    {
        name: 'form2',
        url: '/form2',
        templateUrl: 'form2.html'
    }
];
var formSections = [
    {
        name: 'section1',
        url: '/section1',
        templateUrl: 'section1.html'
    }
];
var sectionPages = [
    {
        name: 'page1',
        parent: 'section1',
        url: '/page1',
        templateUrl: 'page1.html'
    },
    {
        name: 'page2',
        parent: 'section1',
        url: '/page2',
        templateUrl: 'page2.html'
    }
];

function buildState(origState, parent) {
    var state = origState;
    if(parent) {
        //JSON.stringify browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=json.stringify
        state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(origState));
        state.name = state.name + parent.name;
        state.parent = parent.name;
    }
    return state;
}

// Build state hierarchy, push each state object to 'states'
for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    var formState = buildState(forms[i]);
    states.push(formState)
    for(var j = 0; j < formSections.length; j++) {
        var sectionState = buildState(formSections[j], forms[i]);
        states.push(sectionState);
        for(var k = 0; k < sectionPages.length; k++) {
            var pageState = buildState(sectionPages[k], sectionState);
            states.push(pageState);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, `states` contains all of your state objects, which you can pass to the state provider:

```
for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    $stateProvider.state(states[i]);
}
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it's a great way to demonstrate how you could potentially build dynamic paths easily. I've actually found a different way to do what I wanted but this still answered my original question. Thanks for your help and time :)